# Will the linux kernel support Realtek RTL8852BE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe Adapter in the future?

Tags: drivers

Will the newer linux kernels support Realtek RTL8852BE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe Adapter???
I'm asking this question because I have a new laptop (HP Pavilion) and I saw there are some drivers available on github. Looking at the github issues this is not a preferred option ... (I think everyone understands this and wants a out of the box solution distribution)
I would be more pleased to know if some kind of kernel development is done for this driver or not ... ?

Answer (score 1):

It will be in kernel 6.2 so that is the upcomming 23.04. Download it and give the "try Ubuntu" a test run to see if it works out of the box.

The list of supported devices has this on Realtek:

> New Bluetooth hardware support includes the Broadcom BCM4377/4378/4387 chipsets and Realtek RTL8852BE / RTL8723DS.

From [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-6.2-Networking).

Addition: as soon as the point release for the hardware stack for 23.04 is released (ie. `22.04.3` and that will be later this year) it will also be added to the current LTS (22.04).